# H2 + SLF4J: How to log values of PreparedStatement parameters?

Tags: h2, slf4j

My unit test is failing with the following error:

```
JdbcSQLException: NULL not allowed for column "NAME"; SQL statement:
insert into MODULES (NAME)
values ((select ?
from MODULES MODULES
where not exists (select 1
from MODULES MODULES
where MODULES.NAME = ?))) [23502-171]
```

How do I configure H2 to log the values of the PreparedStatement parameters (i.e. actual values instead of `?` placeholders)?

I am currently using [TRACE_LEVEL_FILE=4](http://h2database.com/html/features.html#other_logging).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answering my own question:

I needed to change H2's logging level from "warn" to "debug":

```
<logger name="h2database" level="debug"/>
```